# How to move points in an orthogonal map?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add red points at certain geolocations on the following map created by Mike Bostock. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3795040. My points show up but don't move with the map. How do I edit the code to make the points move with the map. Thank you.

```
//add circles to svg
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([wr,pt,sd,jp,fm])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { console.log(projection(d)); return projection(d)[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
    .attr("r", "8px")
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

The following is what the above array being referenced.

```
//points
var wr = [32.6130007, -83.624201];
var pt = [48.9334357, 8.961208];
var sd = [32.715738, -117.1610838];
var jp = [35.6894875, 139.6917064];
var fm = [39.1137602, -76.7267773];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the circles in the `mousemove` function:

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    var p = d3.mouse(this);
    projection.rotate([λ(p[0]), φ(p[1])]);
    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

    //change the circles' positions here:
    svg.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
            console.log(projection(d));
            return projection(d)[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection(d)[1];
        })
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/2a6f07cdc12838b296674470ad715bbe/54d6de8d73347081f900c88a203019df74f23ade

PS: Some circles appear to move wrongly: they are correct, though. The thing is that they are **behind** the globe. To hide those circles you'll have to write another function (which is outside the scope of this answer).

An alternative to hide the circles behind the globe is using a `path` instead a circle. That way, the projection will automatically clip those paths. Have a look: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9e640195e2c021cd79b5ca9b2238a44c/1c43719a7d6a85d0226cf3c468ac23e570add22d

Comment: @charlie check the new bl.ocks, using paths instead of circles.